# Stellar mass database

Tags: star, mass, star-systems

I need a stellar mass database that also has the distance of the star/system from the sun. Can anybody tell me the name of such of database and where I can find it. I need to do a project on this. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: How far out do you need to consider? 50 ly? 100? 1000?

Comment: 100 lights years will suffice

Comment: [Sol Station](http://www.solstation.com/stars.htm) has stellar mass info as well as distance. Look especially under the "Stars within 100 ly" section. Is this to the level of precision you need?

Comment: http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/optical-IR-prod/nomad is probably overkill, but is the largest current database or stellar data.

Comment: @barrycarter   I can't seem to open the link you provided. my internet won't connect.. Any advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the on-line SIMBAD astronomical data base. You can even make separate lists based on criteria (like: list all of the stars between 10 and 20 parsecs (have to convert parallax to light years/ parsecs = 1/parallax (in arcsec/ 1 parsec = 3.262 LY) with class between G0 and G9 from 0 to +30 deg declination). It's pretty cool and shows numerous listings of distance values, brightness, metallicity, etc. complete with date of study and source. I just looked again and masses aren't listed (sorry). Masses aren't directly measured anyway (except in the case of binaries where we know the distance). Masses are essentially determined from the Hertzprung -Russell (mass/ luminosity) diagram and can be refined if we can determine age by looking at spectra. Back to Sol-Station or Wikipedia or I should say their references.

Comment: There is no complete list of stars out to 100 light years.